# Open phpMyAdmin with preselected database

Tags: url, phpmyadmin

Is there any URL, that I can use as bookmark, that would allow me to open phpMyAdmin and -- after login -- to be redirected to some preselected database, instead of home screen (or what is set in config)?

[image]

I tried this one:

```
http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=dbname
```

But it only works on certain versions of phpMyAdmin and even, if version is the same, it can work on certain set of machines, while on others it fails. So, I presume, that this is a wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct URL should be like that:

```
http://[HOST_AND_PATH]/index.php?db=[DB_NAME]#PMAURL-1:db_structure.php?db=[DB_NAME]
```

I found this path to work in any condition. After logging-in with this path, user should see *phpMyAdmin* open with preselected database (`[DB_NAME]`) and should see that database's tables list, not *pMA*'s home screen.

And, as I just verified this, it works even on as old *phpMyAdmin* as version `2.11.3`.